# UE4 cast to specific class from UUserWidget C++

Tags: c++, casting, unreal-engine4

Let's assume i have 3 cpp class.

1-  Afirst_class : public AActor

2-  Asecond_class : public AActor

3-  Uwidget_class : public UUserWidget

I'm trying to cast from Uwidget_class to Asecond_class. After that from Asecond_class to  Afirst_class.

When i click the UButton(defined in Uwidget_class), OnClicked dynamic executing the related function. In this function i want to cast Asecond_class. Let me visualize that:

Uwidget_class.h :

```
    UPROPERTY(meta = (BindWidget))
         class UTextBlock* button_text;
    UPROPERTY(meta = (BindWidget))
         class UButton* button_to_press;

    public:
        UPROPERTY()
           Asecond_class * test_actor;
```

Uwidget_class.cpp :

```
void Uwidget_class::NativeConstruct(){
    Super::NativeConstruct();
    button_to_press-> OnClicked.AddUniqueDynamic(this,&Uwidget_class::on_click_cast_func);
}

void Uwidget_class::on_click_cast_func(){
    test_actor = Cast<Asecond_class >(this);              //problem might be "this" parameter?
    if (test_actor ==nullptr)
    {
         UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("DIDN'T CAST SUCCESSFULLY"));
    }
    else {
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("CASTED SUCCESSFULLY"));
    }
}
```

Always test_actor will be nullptr. When i use the same casting from Asecond_class to Afirst_class  it works. Should i casting differently when i am using UUserWidget ?

How can i get this Asecond_class in UUserWidget? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to cast from a widget to an actor. In order for casting to work, the two objects involved need to be the same. For example, casting from an actor to a character only works if the actor is literally a character. The only thing casting nets you is more information about an object you already have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like George said in his comment, that cannot work.  Cast is for moving around an inheritance tree, but only along the parts of that tree that are directly related to the actual class of the object being referenced.

So you could cast both your widget and actors to `UObjects`, but I suspect that's about as common as they'll get.

It sounds like you need to grab the actor you want at an earlier stage, and save it in a variable (right click, "promote to variable" in blueprint, but you're in c++ so just declare a member variable and use it... is this what `test_actor` is for?).  And later, rather than the casting something unrelated to the end product you want, just use the member variable.

---

It seems like you're missing a fundamental understanding of what "casting" is.

There are two kinds of casting.  Up and down.

"Up casting" (and I'm sure there are other terms too) is taking your `Asecond_class`, and cast it back into an `AActor`, or anything else higher up the inheritance tree.

"Down casting" (other terms yada yada), is taking a pointer or reference of an `AActor` and **trying** to cast it to an `Asecond_class`.  If the `AActor` in question was created as an instance of one of the 141 other things that inherit from `AActor`, then trying to cast it to `Asecond_actor` will fail, and rightly so.  Treating the memory set aside for an `AGameplayAbilityTargetActor` like it was an Asecond_actor would be Bad... like "crossing the streams" Bad (that's a Ghostbusters reference for those of you not up on your US popular culture).

There's actually considerably more than 141.  I searched the UE4_26 codebase for ": public AActor", and it returned 141 hits.  That doesn't include things that inherit from more than one base class (not for the faint of heart), or things that inherit from any of the aforemented 141 instances of things that inherit from AActor first.

There are other complexities to casting, but I suggest you wrap your head around this properly before you try to understand what a "virtual base class" is, and why C++ needs such a thing in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you are trying to cast the UUserWidget object `this` to AActor which will not work, since the widget itself is not derived from AActor.

Solution: If you really want to access "Asecond_class" (AActor) from your widget you need to save a pointer `AActor*` to that object (e.g. when the widget is initialized) and use that pointer for your cast. But if that object will always be an "Asecond_class", you can simply store a `Asecond_class*` and avoid casting altogether.

Using a generic AActor pointer member stored in the widget:

```
AActor* savedActorPtr; 
// pass in as argument when the widget is initialized and set the saved pointer
```

Then, if you really want to cast:

```
Asecond_class* secActorPtr = Cast<Asecond_class>(savedActorPtr);
if (secActorPtr) 
{ 
 // cast successful, you can now use secActorPtr to access the actor
 secActorPtr->yourClickFunction();
}
```

Or, avoiding the unnecessary cast:

```
Asecond_class* savedSecPtr; 
// same as savedActorPtr before, but always using target type, so no need to cast

if (savedSecPtr) 
{
 savedSecPtr->yourClickFunction();
} 
else 
{
 // error: pointer was never set or actor was deleted
}
```

Assuming what you actually want is to access an actor object from an unrelated UUserWidget.